# Is there an example file for building source file and target file?

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, microsoft-translator

I need to build a .docx source file and target file. The source file content is "Microsoft". The target file content is "微软". Can you instruct me how to build the source file and target file?

I need to translate Microsoft to 微软

Comment: Can you provide some more details regarding the task you're trying to do?

Comment: Are you facing issue with the translation or create source and target file? Can you give details on what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the provided details, you are looking for example to create source and target file.

To create a custom translator with custom source and target file you can check this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/translator/custom-translator/quickstart) and this [sample dataset](https://github.com/MicrosoftTranslator/CustomTranslatorSampleDatasets) which contain both sample  source file and target file.

To do document translation with source file and generate the target file, you can check this [sample code](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/main/sdk/translation/azure-ai-translation-document/samples/sample_begin_translation.py).

**Note:** Make source to select required permission while creating the SAS URL of source and target file.